# StreamBuilder doesn't get rebuilt if Firestore initially return 0 documents?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` from Firestore using this code:

```
static Stream<List<Item>> getItems(String garageId) {
return Firestore.instance
    .collection('bag')
    .document(garageId)
    .collection('items')
    .snapshots()
    .map((event) => event.documents.map((e) => mapToItem(e)).toList());}
```

And I use in-stream builder this way

```
  Widget buildItemList(String garageId, context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Item>>(
      stream: ItemService.getItems(garage.id),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children = new List();
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 0) {
          snapshot.data.forEach((e) => children.add(ItemWidget(item: e)));
          children.add(buildItemAddBox(context));
          return ItemsList(
            items: children,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          #return error widget;
        } else {
          #return empty widget;
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This piece of code allows the Rebuilding of the Widget every time there is a change in the documents in Firestore.

However, if the original `ItemService.getItems()` has 0 documents, after adding 1 new document, the Widget doesn't get rebuild. I have to refresh the page for it to show up. From then on, every new document will trigger the rebuilding of the widget.

Does anyone know how to get it to rebuild the widget when the items is from 0 to 1 documents on Firestore?

Comment: It seems like you are creating a future only for a given item (garage.id) on the list. Can you try something like ItemService.getItems()? You should aim to get them all.

Comment: Hi, to clarify, in 1 garage.id, there can be 0...n number of items. So when I get (garageId), then get ('items") collections. I am intended to get 0...n items in that garage